# RSIllegalArgumentException: Unsuported element type on Android 17

Tags: java, android, renderscript

I've recently published my app on Google Play. I'm checking out the crashes from Firebase and one of the clusters with the highest number of exceptions is a fatal exception with the following stack trace:

```
Caused by android.renderscript.RSIllegalArgumentException: Unsuported element type.
android.renderscript.ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create (ScriptIntrinsicBlur.java:50)
com.kayimapps.autocolorsplash_android.Util.getBlurredBitmap (Util.java:234)
com.kayimapps.autocolorsplash_android.activities.IntroActivity.onCreate (IntroActivity.java:83)
android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:5283)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1097)
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2209)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2299)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$700 (ActivityThread.java:150)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1280)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:137)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5283)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Method.java)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:511)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1102)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:869)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (NativeStart.java)
```

The getBlurredBitmap method that can be seen in the stack trace is also as follows:

```
public static Bitmap getBlurredBitmap(Bitmap input, Context context)
{
    Bitmap result = null;
    try {
        RenderScript rsScript = RenderScript.create(context);
        Allocation alloc = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rsScript, input);

        ScriptIntrinsicBlur blur = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rsScript, alloc.getElement());
        blur.setRadius(25);
        blur.setInput(alloc);

        result = Bitmap.createBitmap(input.getWidth(), input.getHeight(), input.getConfig());
        Allocation outAlloc = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rsScript, result);
        blur.forEach(outAlloc);
        outAlloc.copyTo(result);

        rsScript.destroy();
    }
    catch (RSIllegalArgumentException e)
    {
        FirebaseCrash.report(e);
    }
    return result;
}
```

I've looked everywhere for this exception to see its cause but so far I've found nothing. The interesting thing is that this exception is raised only in devices with Android 17 (4.2), and the only device I'm testing the app with is a Samsung Galaxy S3 with Android 17, which raises no exceptions on that exact same place.

I'm guessing that since RenderScript runs on GPU, maybe some devices simply don't support it because of their hardware. The devices that raise this exception are all sorts of devices with all sorts of brands though, so I can't really blame it on one manufacturer.

Does anyone have any idea on why this would happen, or maybe some pointers on where to look for the solution?

**Edit**: Turns out I am an idiot and the OS version of the phone I'm using is 18, not 17. The problems still persists on devices with Android 17 though.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html#access-rs-apis

Comment: And which element type are you using? Can you provide a snippet of your `ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create()` call?

Comment: @Pavlus I added the code snippet. Also the problem seems to be caused by the Allocation class. After a brief look at the `createFromBitmap()` method of Allocation, it is clear that different parameters are used to create Allocation objects for targetSdkVersion >= 18. I have no idea about the rationale behind this though.